# Task-like objects support in Kestrel

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0, kestrel

I am trying to return [task-like object](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-asynchronous-function) from the controller action:

```
    [HttpGet("test")]
    public async FuncAwaitable<string> GetAsync() => "OK";
```

It works in the VS2019 wizard generated ASP.NET Core solution but fails with Kestrel:

The problem is somewhere in middleware:

```
ArgumentException
System.ArgumentException: 'this' type cannot be an interface itself.
   at System.RuntimeTypeHandle.VerifyInterfaceIsImplemented(RuntimeTypeHandle interfaceHandle)
   at System.RuntimeType.GetInterfaceMap(Type ifaceType)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeReflectionExtensions.GetRuntimeInterfaceMap(TypeInfo typeInfo, Type interfaceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.AwaitableInfo.IsTypeAwaitable(Type type, AwaitableInfo& awaitableInfo)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.CoercedAwaitableInfo.IsTypeAwaitable(Type type, CoercedAwaitableInfo& info)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor..ctor(MethodInfo methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Create(MethodInfo methodInfo, TypeInfo targetTypeInfo, Object[] parameterDefaultValues)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerCache.GetCachedResult(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvokerProvider.OnProvidersExecuting(ActionInvokerProviderContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ActionInvokerFactory.CreateInvoker(ActionContext actionContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.MvcAttributeRouteHandler.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.<RouteAsync>b__0(HttpContext c)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.RouterMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Shared.AspNetCore.CorrelationHeader.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<<UseCorrelation>b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\proj\ah\shared\src\Shared.AspNetCore\AspNetCore\CorrelationHeader.cs:line 16
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you're actually trying to achieve here. An action is supposed to return a result type or something that can be coerced into a result natively. For example, if you were an array of objects or something, ASP.NET Core is smart enough to wrap that in an `ObjectResult` so it gets serialized. However, something like a `Func` is not serializable. It literally needs to be called, and there's nothing in the response pipeline that would actually *do* that.

Comment: Starting C# 7.0 we could use [Generalized async return types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-7#generalized-async-return-types), e.g.: [FuncAwaitable](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/functional-csharp-asynchronous-function). I use custom return type to enrich result with extra properties in Swagger compatible way, so in my case controller actions returning `Schedulable<T>`  instead of `Task<T>` automatically support `X-DELAY` HTTP header to delay execution and provide alternative result when action is just become scheduled.

Comment: Just because you can do something on a class method doesn't mean you can also do that on an actions. Actions are invoked by the request pipeline and need very specific return types because of that.

Comment: You can, if you want, actually create a custom result type that either implements IActionResult or inherits from an existing result type like ObjectResult, and in that modify the headers. Or you might do this as a response filter, or even some piece of middleware. However, the method you're using here won't work.

Comment: It works with `Microsoft-IIS/10.0` though. I will try custom IActionResult - thanks, but it would make controllers non-handy for testing...

Comment: Generally speaking, it works everywhere with Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web on Linux/Mac/Windows. Probably just `UseKestrel` is problematic...